# How does a beam splitter split a reflected beam? (experiential data)

Tags: optics, photons, reflection, structural-beam

[image: Pic of setup]

Modtager = receiver. Prøve = sample.

An beam is emitted from the emitter send to the beam splitter and is devided into two as shown in the figure. From the sample (prøve) the beam is reflected and now send back to the beamsplitter.

I mesure that the reflected beam reaches the receiver, question is how. I have come to the conclusion that b1 must be a mirror for the reflection of the sample to reach the receiver. Is this true? ¨

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how signal from the sample makes it to the detector. The beam splitter should be rotated 90 degrees (unless you really just want to sample the emitter.

Comment: Light reflected from the sample gets reflected ‘downward’ by the beam splitter. Exactly as expected. But if that light then strikes something reflective, some light goes back upward to the beam splitter and then through to the receiver. Properly designed beam stops are useful, especially with lasers. I am actually taking advantage of this to combine three light sources: a hollow cathode lamp, a white LED, and a 532 nm laser. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the beam splitter is made from some very special material or of particular structure, the picture in the question is wrong. The laws of reflection dictate that the beam from sample to splitter is reflected *downwards*.

Do you actually "measure" something, or is this a simulation? GeoGebra maybe? I think the splitter is just drawn wrong, it has to be rotated by 90 degrees.

Comment: I mean measure, the pic is a illustation of the set up. What I'm in doubt about is how the beam splitter is placed. 

But I think you're right. 
The turning of the beam splitter does not produce a signal dicertly from the emitter to the receiver, meaning that if the sampel is removed there shoud be no signal. There is though.

Answer (score 0):

the beam splitter can be though of as an inefficient mirror, where half the light that strikes it goes straight through instead of being reflected.  where in DK bor du?